# Saved bundle doesn't contain data

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have 2 serializable objects that I want to retain after my fragment is rebuilt. Therefore I saved them during onSaveInstanceState (the objects are not null here):

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putSerializable(RENDERER, renderer);
    outState.putSerializable(SERIES, series);
}
```

In the onCreate method of the fragment I try to get them out of the Bundle:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        renderer = (DefaultRenderer) savedInstanceState.getSerializable(RENDERER);
        series = (CategorySeries) savedInstanceState.getSerializable(SERIES);
    }
}
```

The problem is that "renderer" and "series" are always null after calling getSerializable. Any ideas why?

Comment: You said that after your fragment is rebuilt, but these methods are from Activity lifecycle

Comment: can u putInt and see if its working?

Comment: I tried putString and it worked! I really don't get it...

Comment: I figured out that the casts to (DefaultRenderer) and (CategorySeries) make the object null. If I don't cast it and leave it as Serializable the object is not null. What could this be?

Comment: I figured out that the assignment (DefaultRenderer) savedInstanceState.getSerializable(RENDERER) to renderer doesn't work. If I take a new Object "DefaultRenderer test = savedInstanceState.getSerializable(RENDERER)" the assignment works! What kind of sorcery is this?

Answer (score 3):

Did you override `onSaveInstanceState` method in `FragmentActivity` that hosts this fragment?
 If you're, then make sure that it should call `super.onSaveInstanceState(Bundle)`.

Comment: I didn't override it.

Comment: Then please, override it.

Comment: But everything is called correctly. I just can't assign any values to member variables. Only to local variables.